# how to work with linq association, entity isn't available

Tags: c#, linq

I have the below query working in linqpad, but it doesn't work when I put it in Visual Studios because aspnet_UsersInRoles shows up as an association in the edmx instead of an entity.  How can I fix this?

```
var memberships = from m in  First5MembershipDB.aspnet_Membership
                  join u in First5MembershipDB.aspnet_Users on m.UserId equals u.UserId
                  join ur in First5MembershipDB.Aspnet_UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals ur.UserId
                  join r in First5MembershipDB.aspnet_Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.RoleId
                  join a in First5MembershipDB.Applications on r.WebApplicationID equals a.ApplicationId
```

Comment: Use the associate.  `u.Members`

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're doing this in LINQ Pad are you using the same entities (edmx) that are defined in your project, or are you using the auto-generated models (LINQ to SQL)? If EF sees Aspnet_UsersInRoles as a Many-Many table, it may optimize it out and require you to access it as follows:

```
var memberships = from m in  First5MembershipDB.aspnet_Membership
                  join u in First5MembershipDB.aspnet_Users on m.UserId equals u.UserId
                  from r in u.aspnet_Roles
                  join a in First5MembershipDB.Applications on r.WebApplicationID equals a.ApplicationId
```